# PHP and COM : error "Invalid syntax"

Tags: php, dll

I'm trying to connect to a dll that was supplied to me, I don't have the ability to edit it.
Is the "Invalid syntax" error refering to a method within the dll or something with the php code?

```
try {
    $testConnection = new COM("SomebodySpecial.DLL");
} catch (com_exception $e) {
    echo "";
    print_r( array( 'errorCode' => $e->getCode(),
                    'errorMessage' => $e->getMessage(),
                    'errorFile' => $e->getFile(),
                    'errorLine' => $e->getLine()));  
    echo "";  
}

[errorCode] => -2147221020
[errorMessage] => Failed to create COM object `SomebodySpecial.DLL': Invalid syntax
[errorFile] => D:\Inetpub\wwwroot-dev\test.php
[errorLine] => 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message indicates, you provided an invalid parameter to the `COM` constructor.

[The parameter is a COM ID, not a DLL filename.](http://php.net/manual/en/class.com.php)

Comment: @Ronn - What is a COM ID ?

Comment: @vishnu: Simply click on the link in my answer to find out.