# Diagnose a PHP/IIS crash issue

Tags: php, iis

I have PHP 5.6 running on IIS8.  The server seems to run fine for a number of days, then I get:

```
[13-Nov-2015 14:46:02 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed to create COM object `ADODB.Connection': Invalid syntax
' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dbconnections.php:9
Stack trace:
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dbconnections.php(9): com->com('ADODB.Connectio...')
#1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\linkedfiles.php(20): include('C:\\inetpub\\wwwr...')
#2 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\login.php(61): include('C:\\inetpub\\wwwr...')
#3 {main}
  thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dbconnections.php on line 9
```

If I restart the IIS service, obviously all is fine again.  I am just not sure where to start to diagnose.

Comment: may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589594/php-and-com-error-invalid-syntax

Comment: I don't believe this to be within the scope of SO, please try [superuser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: first, surround your code by try/catch() ... :) and can you please show us how do you create your COM Objects ?